# Automatic acception of invitations

Tags: vba, outlook

Microsoft Outlook has the option to accept all calendar invitations automatically, but it doesn't check if the slot is free.

The option to reject all invitations in case the slot isn't available isn't good at all. If somebody shifts an one hour meeting e.g. 30 minutes it rejects the invitation cause the slot isn't free. Weered!

I try to find a solution with VBA cause I handle also different senders and so on

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How can I check if the timeslot of an invitation is available or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Aplication.Session.CurrentUser.FreeBusy` method.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.